# Playing two video with axWindowsMediaPlayer

Tags: c#, .net

I try to play jpg (in loop), after click mp4 should be played after end, that jpg should play again. I dont know why but after I play in axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange vido play and then stop. Help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Video
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool clicked = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "wait2.JPG";

        }



        private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
        {
            if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded & clicked== true)
            {
                clicked = false;
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode("Loop", true);
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "wait2.JPG";
                axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();

            }

        }

        private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_ClickEvent(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_ClickEvent e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode("Loop", false);
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "video.MP4";
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            clicked = true;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wish someone had replied to this question the time it was posted. It took me a lot of time to figure out why I was not able to start a new video by setting the URL property. I finally found the answer to this issue here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562470%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The problem is with setting the URL property from within the axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange() event handler. According to the above msdn document:

"Do not call this method from event handler code. Calling URL from an event handler may yield unexpected results."

So the URL property has to be set outside of the even handler. I also tried Dispatcher.Invoke() and even starting a new thread from within the event handler to set the URL property; but that too did not help. It really has to come from outside of the event handler!

Comment: Thanks for putting it here! That was useful information. +1 to question as well as the answer.