# Can't play two audio clips using Windows Media Player library

Tags: c#, windows, audio, mp3, media-player

This is probably a really easy fix, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out.

What I am attempting to do is play two audio clips conescutively in my C# project. However, I do not want the next clip to play until the first clip is done playing.

In summary, this is what I am doing (old code):

```
public static void PlayAudioClip(string path)
{
    Console.WriteLine(path) // Just so we know which file is playing.
    wplayer.controls.stop();
    wplayer.URL = path;
    wplayer.controls.play();
}

public static void CharacterTalking()
{
    PlayAudioClip(@"C:\Game\Audio\Hello world.mp3");
    PlayAudioClip(@"C:\Game\Audio\How are you today.mp3");
}
```

Now, instead of playing both clips one after the other, neither clip actually plays. I've been unable to figure out why.

I'd *prefer* to use the Windows Media Player library for this, but if you have another suggestion, feel free to share. I am not required to use Windows Media Player for this.

A similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644754/how-to-detect-when-a-mp3-file-has-finished-playing/17645100#17645100) explains how to loop a file, but that isn't what I want to do. It's helpful in explaining that I can use an event handler to check the state of a file, but that hasn't helped me in this solution. Or maybe it has, and I'm just overthinking it.

EDIT: It occurs to me I didn't explain this earlier. Apologies. Assume that these two audio files I have given are *not* the only two the program will eventually have. I want to have my PlayAudioClip() function *always* wait for the previous clip to finish playing.

///////////////////////////////////////

EDIT 2: This is a really complicated round-about way of doing this, but here's my new attempt, using some information I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644754/how-to-detect-when-a-mp3-file-has-finished-playing/17645100#17645100).

New Code:

```
public static List<String> Playlist = new List<string>();
public static void AddToPlaylist(string path)
{
    Playlist.Add(path);
    Console.WriteLine("Queued " + path);
}

public static void RunPlaylist()
{
    PlayAudioClip(Playlist.First());
}

private void Wplayer_PlayStateChange(int NewState)
{
    switch (NewState)
    {
        case 0:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsUndefined", ConsoleColor.DarkGray);
            break;
        case 1:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsStopped", ConsoleColor.Red);
            try
            {
                Playlist.Remove(Playlist.First());
                try
                {
                    PlayAudioClip(Playlist.First());
                }
                catch
                {
                    WriteFancyConsoleLine("Playlist is now empty!", ConsoleColor.DarkRed);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                WriteFancyConsoleLine("Playlist already empty!", ConsoleColor.DarkRed);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsPaused", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
            break;
        case 3:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsPlaying", ConsoleColor.Green);
            break;
        case 4:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsScanForward", ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta);
            break;
        case 5:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsScanReverse", ConsoleColor.Magenta);
            break;
        case 6:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsBuffering", ConsoleColor.Gray);
            break;
        case 7:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsWaiting", ConsoleColor.DarkYellow);
            break;
        case 8:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsMediaEnded", ConsoleColor.DarkRed);
            break;
        case 9:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsTransitioning", ConsoleColor.DarkGray);
            break;
        case 10:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsReady", ConsoleColor.Magenta);
            break;
        case 11:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsReconnecting", ConsoleColor.Magenta);
            break;
        case 12:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsLast", ConsoleColor.DarkBlue);
            break;
    }
}

public static void PlayAudioClip(string path)
{
    WriteFancyConsoleLine("Playing " + path, ConsoleColor.Gray);
    wplayer.controls.stop();
    wplayer.URL = path;
    wplayer.controls.play();
}

private void CharacterTalking() // This is where the magic happens.
{
    AddToPlaylist(@"C:\Game\Audio\Hello world.mp3");
    AddToPlaylist(@"C:\Game\Audio\How are you today.mp3");
    RunPlaylist();
}
```

However, the second audio clip still doesn't play. In the console, after wmppsStopped appears, it says it tries to play the next clip, but then just jumps between wmppsTransitioning and wmppsReady a few times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when a mp3 file has finished playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644754/how-to-detect-when-a-mp3-file-has-finished-playing)

Comment: I agree with Camilo, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17645100/783284) in particular may help you. I'm voting to close this, but if you find that the answer in that question doesn't get you where you need to be - post your findings again with where it got you and where you're stuck.

Comment: I think I stumbled on that answer the other night but couldn't find it again when I posted this question. Anyway, the issue with that answer is that in their example, they are attempting to repeat the same clip of audio. That is not what I want to do here.

Maybe I overlooked something. Let me try reviewing it again.

Comment: Yea, that isn't really the solution I want. That example only asks about looping. I tried experimenting with that solution the other day and either I didn't understand, or it doesn't work. I didn't post in that question at the time because I felt like I was hijacking the thread.

Comment: @SpadesNeil, yes, that question is specifically for looping. Still, you should be able to use the same concept to come up with a solution for your problem. I would attempt again with using that to come up with something and post your findings so we can see where things could have gone wrong.

Comment: @Cody I understand the use of handling when the player changes states, but the problem with this solution, or perhaps a problem with how I am trying to solve the problem, lies in the fact these two audio clips aren't the only ones I will eventually want to play. Currently, it looks like the only way I can get both audio clips to play with that solution is by playing through one, waiting for it to stop, and when the stop function is called, to start playing the next clip directly from the event handler. This stops being practical when I want to add more audio files than the two I have already.

Comment: Okay, actually, I may have gotten closer to a solution. I edited my post substantially.

Answer (score 1):

Create a **PlayList**, add your songs, then play the list:

```
WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist Playlist = wplayer.newPlaylist("MyPlayList", "");  
Playlist.appendItem(wplayer.newMedia(@"C:\Game\Audio\Hello world.mp3"));
Playlist.appendItem(wplayer.newMedia(@"C:\Game\Audio\How are you today.mp3"));
wplayer.currentPlaylist = Playlist;
wplayer.controls.play();
```

Comment: I think you left a typo on the last line, but this might be what I am looking for! Is there any way to also clear the playlist when I am done?

EDIT: Nvm, it's wplayer.currentPlaylist.clear();

Comment: Not sure what the difference is, it works perfectly on my system.  I also have to use "Ctlcontrols" instead of "controls" on my computer.

Comment: According to Visual Studio 2017: *'WindowsMediaPlayer' does not contain a definition for 'Ctlcontrols' and no extension method 'Ctlcontrols' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsMediaPlayer' could be found.*

Comment: Here's the documentation for [AxWindowsMediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562401(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was found here:

[Mediaplayer WinForm won't play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564891/mediaplayer-winform-wont-play)

The reason the two clips won't play immediately after each other is because Windows Media Player needs a little bit of time to get ready for the next clip, or it breaks down.

By instead setting a boolean in the change play state, and calling the next list item from a timer instead, the program now works.

```
public static List<String> Playlist = new List<string>();
public static void AddToPlaylist(string path)
{
    Playlist.Add(path);
    Console.WriteLine("Queued " + path);
}

public static void RunPlaylist()
{
    try
    {
        PlayStateStopped = false;
        PlayAudioClip(Playlist.First());
        Playlist.Remove(Playlist.First());
    }
    catch
    {
        WriteFancyConsoleLine("Playlist is empty.", ConsoleColor.Red);
    }
}

private void Wplayer_PlayStateChange(int NewState)
{
    switch (NewState)
    {
        case 0:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsUndefined", ConsoleColor.DarkGray);
            break;
        case 1:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsStopped", ConsoleColor.Red);
            PlayStateStopped = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsPaused", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
            break;
        case 3:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsPlaying", ConsoleColor.Green);
            break;
        case 4:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsScanForward", ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta);
            break;
        case 5:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsScanReverse", ConsoleColor.Magenta);
            break;
        case 6:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsBuffering", ConsoleColor.Gray);
            break;
        case 7:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsWaiting", ConsoleColor.DarkYellow);
            break;
        case 8:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsMediaEnded", ConsoleColor.DarkRed);
            break;
        case 9:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsTransitioning", ConsoleColor.DarkGray);
            break;
        case 10:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsReady", ConsoleColor.Magenta);
            break;
        case 11:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsReconnecting", ConsoleColor.Magenta);
            break;
        case 12:
            WriteFancyConsoleLine("PlayState = wmppsLast", ConsoleColor.DarkBlue);
            break;
    }
}

public static void PlayAudioClip(string path)
{
    WriteFancyConsoleLine("Playing " + path, ConsoleColor.Gray);
    wplayer.controls.stop();
    wplayer.URL = path;
    wplayer.controls.play();
    PlayStateStopped = false;
}

// Remember that timer1.Enabled = true; has to be set somewhere.
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PlayStateStopped)
    {
        RunPlaylist();
    }
}
```

Comment: does this work if you have a UI control STOP button? I want to know when the media has finished not when the user had pressed stop.